# Failing to initialize 1.8" SSD connected to USB

Tags: windows, ssd, sata, msata

I salvaged a 1.8" SSD from an old laptop and want to make it an external USB drive. I already have a SATA to USB connector, but I got [this](http://a.co/a6HR1g3) micro SATA to SATA converter to get everything hooked up.

However, when I plug in the drive (Windows 10) the drive isn't immediately available (I assume because it is uninitialized). Using the Disk Management tool, I see:

[image: Disk Management]

Trying to initialize it gives me an I/O device error:

[image: disk management error]

Using diskpart, I am not having any luck either:

```
DISKPART> select disk 2

Disk 2 is now the selected disk.

DISKPART> clean

DiskPart succeeded in cleaning the disk.

DISKPART> convert gpt

DiskPart has encountered an error: The request could not be performed because of an I/O device error.
See the System Event Log for more information.

DISKPART> convert mbr
```

Any ideas on what is going on? I am fairly certain the drive is still working as it was fine when it was in the laptop. I initially thought this was the mSATA to SATA adapter, but this was the second adapter I've tried. The drive itself came in an enclosure like thing that had an mSATA to SATA adapter, but I had the same results.

I read somewhere that 1.8" drives require 3.3V power, but I'm not sure if that has something to do with it as I am seeing the drive listed in the tools.

Comment: I would try a different USB to Sata converter and and/or a different msata to sata converter.

Comment: Actually this is the second adapter I tried, the drive came out of the laptop in an enclosure that had an mSATA to SATA connection. I just got this new one and got the same results.